# Twitter Bootstrap Closing Modal

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap to make a project that opens modals with buttons.  Each modal closes if you click on the same button that opens it.  The modals will also close if you press escape or click on the background.  However, if you click on the button to open one modal and then the button for another modal, the code opens both modals.  If any modal is open, I want it to close when you click anywhere else on the page, including any of the other buttons.  I'm really lost with the JavaScript, though.

Comment: I can't replicate what you describe. Can you post a small example of your code? Maybe modify this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkHtW/) and repost it so you can show us what you mean.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and in what ways Bootstrap isn't doing it for you. Since clicking anywhere else on the page closes the modal, how can you click a button to open another modal? Is that button in the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears vague, so I will try to touch most of the points so that your question gets answered.

If you want the [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) should not close on pressing esc or clicking some where else then try this....

```
    <a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static"
 data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

To show a modal. use this inside a javascript function:

```
 $('#myModal').modal('show')
```

To hide a modal use this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

To toggle a modal use this:

```
 $('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

Use these according to your need, hide a modal when you need may be on a button click.

I think this much is sufficient to achieve whatever you need.

If anything you aren't able to get something please post a comment.

Cheers!!!